# Whining sound when turning wheel

Tags: chevrolet, noise, steering, sonic

I have a 2017 Chevy sonic RS. It began making a whining sound when turning the steering wheel about a month ago. I found a tear in the boot and replaced both ball joints and control arms. The noise persists and so does my frustration. The car has electric power steering so it can’t be a power steering fluid issue. It is a lot more notable at lower speeds, however it seems present regardless of the speed. I’m wondering if it could be a faulty steering rack? I have no issues with turning the steering wheel whatsoever, no knocking or grinding sounds. It kind of sounds like rubber, rubbing against rubber. It occurs when the vehicle is stationary, off, and while driving when turning the wheel. Any input would be appreciated!

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Comment: Are you saying you get the sound when you turn the wheel with the engine off, or not turning the wheel?

Comment: The sound is whenever the wheel is turned, with the engine on or off, sorry. With the engine off the wheel is more or less locked in place but the wiggle that it does give, you can hear the sound. I think it may be the strut bushings so I’ll take a peak this weekend and update once I have.

Comment: This would be much easier to diagnose if we could hear the sound. Could you record a video, post it somewhere, and then add a link to the video to this question?